Jinja Code coming up as text from Flask to HTML webpage
I have been attempting to flash a simple message to a webpage via Flask and Jinja, and yet it always reuslts in the jinja code being displayed as simple text.
Here is my app.py code:
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '12345'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    flash('Hello, this is a flash message!')
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Here is my index.html code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flash Message Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for mesg in get_flashed_messages() %}
        <h1>{{ mesg }}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>

My directory structure is very simple:

I have tried almost everything, looked and adpated multiple tutorials, simplified the program to its skeleton, uninstalled and re-installed Flask, but still the Jinja Code comes up as text like so:

What am I missing here?

Your code is fine, everything is set up correctly. It appears that you are manually opening your index.html file in the browser (i.e., double-clicking index.html). For your page to display correctly, you need to start your server and then navigate to the home route to see the correct page.
Start the server:
python app.py
You should get some output like this:
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: xxx-xxx-xxx

Then, open your browser and navigate to http://127.0.0.1:5000. The page should display correctly.
